# Displaying header dependent on page in php

Tags: php, wordpress, operators

I have no idea why this is not working

```
<?php $title = the_title(); ?>

<h1 class="top-entry-title">

  <?php if( $title === "News" ): ?>

     <?php the_title(); ?>

   <?php endif; ?></h1>
```

it just shows the title for every page even if it isn't equal to news ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the top.

```
$title = the_title();
```

will print the title. See also the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

Answer (score 0):

There's no `echo` in your code (and it's way too complicated, I think):

```
<?php
    if( $title === "News" )
        echo "News";
?>
```

should do the job.

Comment: He says it prints always. Even without any `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

This would print the title to the screen as an h1.

Read here wordpress doc [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)